# Prove that are no rational $a, b$, such that $\sqrt[3]{2} = a + b \sqrt 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction but I don't know what to do with the $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Dóra Spitzner The square radical of $2$ requires elevating to the $2$nd power in order to yield a rational value. The cubic radical of $2$ however cannot do with anything less than an elevation to the $3$rd power in order to return to $\mathbb{Q}$, poetically speaking. The rational coefficients $a$ and $b$ should only affect the minimal necessary operations required to ''bring $a+b\sqrt{2}$ back to $\mathbb{Q}$" by introducing some new rational coefficients, but not by modifying the degree....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were two rational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt[3]{2}=a+b\sqrt{2}$, then by raising to the third power both sides of the previous equality, we would get that

$2=a^3+3a^2b\sqrt{2}+6ab^2+2b^3\sqrt{2}$,

$b\left(3a^2+2b^2\right)\sqrt{2}=2-a^3-6ab^2.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

But $\;b\ne0\;$ because otherwise $a^3=2$ which is impossible indeed it does not have any rational solution.

$b\ne0\implies 3a^2+2b^2>0\;,\;$ so from $(*)$ it follows that

$\sqrt{2}=\cfrac{2-a^3-6ab^2}{b\left(3a^2+2b^2\right)}\in\mathbb{Q}$

which contradicts the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.

Hence there do not exist rational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt[3]{2}=a+b\sqrt{2}$, otherwise it would lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Don't know what to do with $\sqrt[3]2$? Think again. Since it's a *cube* root, the only sensible thing to do with it is to *cube* it. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$.

If $\sqrt[3]{2} = a + b \sqrt 2$, then $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=(x-a)^2-2b^2$. Since $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x)=x^3-2$, then $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $1$ with rational coefficients (*). But this cannot happen because $\alpha$ is irrational.

(*) Write $g(x)=f(x)q(x)+r(x)$. Then $\alpha$ is a root of $r(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem, we know that $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now on the contrary let's assume such $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ exists.
$$ \sqrt[3]{2} = a + b\sqrt{2} \implies 2 = a^3 + b^3\sqrt{8} + 3\sqrt{2}ab (a + b \sqrt{2})  $$
$$\implies 2  = a^3 + b^3\sqrt{8} + 3\sqrt{2} a^2b + 6 ab^2 $$
$$ \implies 2 - a^3 -6ab^2 = b^3\sqrt{8} + 3\sqrt{2} a^2b  $$
Now note that the L.H.S $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and R.H.S $\not\in \mathbb{Q}$. Thus we are done!

**Edit:** If the R.H.S is rational, then,
$$ b^3\sqrt{8} + 3\sqrt{2} a^2b = b\underbrace{(b^2\sqrt{8} + 3\sqrt{2} a^2 )}_{\not\in \mathbb{Q}} \in \mathbb{Q} \iff b = 0 $$
But if $b = 0$, then we have $ \mathbb{Q} \not\ni \sqrt[3]{2} = a \in \mathbb{Q}$. A **contradiction!**

Comment: R.H.S. would be rational if $b$ were equal to $0$. You did not write why it is impossible that $b=0$.

Comment: Yeah, that is obvious. but I didn't mention it, that's true too. Thanks!